# How do I update a HABTM associated model in CakePHP 1.3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models, Articles and Tags, that are each linked by a hasAndBelongsToMany relationship. Tags can be applied to multiple articles at once, via a function in the Tag model called addTagToArticles. Articles have a status field that stores a 1 for 'active' or 0 for 'archived'. The auto-generated join table ArticlesTag stores the mapping of Tags to Articles and vice-versa. I want to have it where when a particular tag is applied to a set of articles, it will change the article status from active to archived. The article status field is on the articles table though, and not on the articlestag table. What is the right syntax to update an article's status? Do I need to create an on-the-fly hasMany association between Tags and Articles, like that outlined in http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1045/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly?

Here is the relevant code:

tag.php:

```
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Article' => array(
            'className'             => 'Article',
            'joinTable'             => 'articles_tags',
            'foreignKey'            => 'tag_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'article_id',
            'unique'                => true,
            'conditions'            => '',
            'fields'                => '',
            'order'                 => '',
            'limit'                 => '',
            'offset'                => '',
            'finderQuery'           => '',
            'deleteQuery'           => '',
            'insertQuery'           => ''
        ),

    public function addTagToArticles($data) {
        // Map tag to article(s)                                                                                                                                         
        $newtags = array();
        foreach($data['Article'] AS $article_id) {
            $tag_mapping = array(
                'article_id' => $article_id,
                'tag_id' => $data['Tag']['id']
            );
            $newtags[] = $tag_mapping;
        }
        $result = false;
        if (!empty($newtags)) {
            $result = $this->ArticlesTag->saveAll($newtags);
        }
        if ($result) {
            return $data['Tag']['id'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

article.php:

```
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'className'             => 'Tag',
            'joinTable'             => 'articles_tags',
            'foreignKey'            => 'article_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'unique'                => true,
            'dependent'             => true,
    'conditions'            => '',
            'fields'                => '',
            'order'                 => '',
            'limit'                 => '',
            'offset'                => '',
            'finderQuery'           => '',
            'deleteQuery'           => '',
            'insertQuery'           => ''
        )
    );
```

Here is what I've tried inside the foreach loop inside the addTagToArticles function, inside tag.php:

```
            ...
            if ($data['Tag']['name'] == 'special_tag' ) {
                $article = $this->Article->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $article_id)));
                $article['Article']['status'] = Article::ARCHIVED;
                $this->Article->save( $article );
            }
            ...
```

but this does not seem to do anything. Is this even the right approach? I'm not seeing any errors in the logs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general it seems OK. Must be some minor error. Is the if statement being called? Is the article found?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the $newTags array in addTagToArticles never gets anything assigned to it.  Yet the saveAll is using it, so saveAll will never save anything.

Comment: @BryanPlasters thanks for pointing out the typo in the example. The example now includes all the relevant production code I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

Do all the articles and tags already exist before you're saving them?

Anyway, I usually save HABTM relations in a different way - I do it by saving one of the main models, not through the association model.

Arrange your data like this below, and do `$this->Tag->save($data);`. That weird double array format ensures the Tag is updated first, and then the ArticlesTag data is updated. It works the other way around too, so you can swap Tag for Article and call `Article->save()` if needed.

Does this help?

```
array(
'Tag' => array(
    'id' => '42'
     // any other tag data you want to update
),
'Articles' => array(
    'Articles' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 0 => '5'
        // list all the articles
    )
),
)
```